# How come bestPoints shows up as NaN on the text for the end screen?

Tags: javascript

So, I have been working on this project for a while, but I can't get bestPoints to work, no matter how I do it.

I have tried using the direct score and time when points > bestPoints, having it just equal points, either way it comes up with some error. I have looked through what I did for all the other variables, and I can't find any difference, so could someone tell me what I need to add or get rid off? Or did I miss something?

```js
// GAME SETUP
//background
var background1 = createSprite(200, 200);
background1.setAnimation("background");
//coin
var coin = createSprite(600, 600);
coin.setAnimation("coin");
var valuechange = 2;
var scale = 0.05 / valuechange;
coin.scale = scale;
//blocks
var rock1 = createSprite(600, 600);
rock1.setAnimation("rock");
var rock2 = createSprite(600, 600);
rock2.setAnimation("rock");
//scaling the objects
rock1.scale = 0.5;
rock2.scale = 0.5;
// create player, target, and obstacles
var player = createSprite(200, 100);
player.setAnimation("bird_left");
player.scale = scale * 10;
//score
var score = 0;
var highScoreSave = 0;
var bestRunScore = 0;
//time
var time = 0;
var bestTime = 0;
var bestRunTime = 0;
//counting
var movespeed = 1;
var count1 = 30;
var count2 = 500 / movespeed;
var count22 = count2;
var count3 = 0;
World.frameRate = 60;
//move speed
var left = 0.25;
var right = 0.25;
var up = 0.5;
//one go variable
var pl3 = 0;
//points
var points = 0;
var bestPoints = 0;
var bestRunPoints = 0;

function draw() {
  //coin random xy spawn positions
  var r1 = randomNumber(61, 339);
  var r2 = randomNumber(61, 339);
  //rock1 random spot spawn
  var r3 = randomNumber(0, 1);
  var r4 = randomNumber(0, 1);
  var r5 = randomNumber(0, 400);
  var r6 = randomNumber(0, 400);
  //rock2 random spot spawn
  var r7 = randomNumber(0, 1);
  var r8 = randomNumber(0, 1);
  var r9 = randomNumber(0, 400);
  var r10 = randomNumber(0, 400);
  //velocity cap
  if (player.velocityY > 7.5) {
    player.velocityY = player.velocityY - 2.5;
  }
  if (player.velocityY < -7.5) {
    player.velocityY = player.velocityY + 2.5;
  }
  if (player.velocityX > 7.5) {
    player.velocityX = player.velocityX - 2.5;
  }
  if (player.velocityX < -7.5) {
    player.velocityX = player.velocityX + 2.5;
  }
  //points going up
  points = score / time;
  points = points * 10;
  points = Math.round(points);
  //best score and time update
  if (score > highScoreSave) {
    highScoreSave = score;
  }
  if (time > bestTime) {
    bestTime = time;
  }
  if (points >= bestPoints) {
    bestPoints = bestRunScore / bestRunTime;
    bestPoints = bestPoints * 10;
    bestPoints = Math.round(bestPoints);
  }
  //points update
  if (score >= highScoreSave && time >= bestTime) {
    bestRunScore = score;
    bestRunTime = time;
  }

  // GAME OVER
  if (player.x < 0 || player.x > 400 || player.y < 0 || player.y > 400) {
    background("black");
    textSize(50);
    fill("green");
    text("Game Over!", 60, 200);
    textSize(20);
    text("Press 'R' to Restart", 110, 300);
    //time and score displayed
    textSize(12.5);
    fill("white");
    //score
    text("Score:" + score, 15, 20);
    //high score
    text("High Score:" + highScoreSave, 15, 50);
    //best run score
    text("Best Run Score:" + bestRunScore, 15, 80);
    //time
    text("Time:" + time, 140, 20);
    //best time
    text("Best Time:" + bestTime, 140, 50);
    //best run time
    text("Best Run Time:" + bestRunTime, 140, 80);
    //points
    text("Points:" + points, 260, 20);
    //best points
    text("Most Points:" + bestPoints, 260, 50);
    //points explenation
    text("Points = Score / Time", 260, 80);
    //covering extra numbers
    fill("black");
    stroke("black");
    rect(353.5, 30, 46.5, 30);
    fill("black");
    stroke("black");
    rect(321, 0, 79, 20);
    if (keyWentDown("p")) {
      score = 0;
      highScoreSave = 0;
      bestRunScore = 0;
      time = 0;
      bestTime = 0;
      bestRunTime = 0;
      points = 0;
      bestPoints = 0;
      bestRunPoints = 0;
    }

    if (keyWentDown("r")) {
      //coin random xy spawn positions
      r1 = randomNumber(61, 339);
      r2 = randomNumber(61, 339);
      //rock1 random spot spawn
      r3 = randomNumber(0, 1);
      r4 = randomNumber(0, 1);
      r5 = randomNumber(0, 400);
      r6 = randomNumber(0, 400);
      //rock2 random spot spawn
      r7 = randomNumber(0, 1);
      r8 = randomNumber(0, 1);
      r9 = randomNumber(0, 400);
      r10 = randomNumber(0, 400);
      //player reset
      player.x = 200;
      player.y = 100;
      player.velocityX = 0;
      player.velocityY = 0;

      //coin spawning
      coin.x = r1;
      coin.y = r2;

      //rock spawning
      //rock1
      if (r3 == 0 && r4 == 0) {
        rock1.x = -50;
        rock1.y = r6;
        rock1.velocityX = movespeed;
        rock1.velocityY = 0;
      }
      if (r3 == 1 && r4 == 0) {
        rock1.x = r5;
        rock1.y = 450;
        rock1.velocityX = 0;
        rock1.velocityY = -movespeed;
      }
      if (r3 == 1 && r4 == 1) {
        rock1.x = 450;
        rock1.y = r6;
        rock1.velocityX = -movespeed;
        rock1.velocityY = 0;
      }
      if (r3 == 0 && r4 == 1) {
        rock1.x = r5;
        rock1.y = -50;
        rock1.velocityX = 0;
        rock1.velocityY = movespeed;
      }
      //rock2
      if (r7 == 0 && r8 == 0) {
        rock2.x = -50;
        rock2.y = r10;
        rock2.velocityX = movespeed;
        rock2.velocityY = 0;
      }
      if (r7 == 1 && r8 == 0) {
        rock2.x = r9;
        rock2.y = 450;
        rock2.velocityX = 0;
        rock2.velocityY = -movespeed;
      }
      if (r7 == 1 && r8 == 1) {
        rock2.x = 450;
        rock2.y = r10;
        rock2.velocityX = -movespeed;
        rock2.velocityY = 0;
      }
      if (r7 == 0 && r8 == 1) {
        rock2.x = r9;
        rock2.y = -50;
        rock2.velocityX = 0;
        rock2.velocityY = movespeed;
      }
      //time and score reset
      time = 0;
      count1 = 30;
      score = 0;
      count2 = 0;
      points = 0;
    }
  } else {

    //coin spawning
    if (pl3 == 0) {
      coin.x = r1;
      coin.y = r2;
      pl3 = 1;
    }

    //rock spawning
    if (count2 == count22) {
      count2 = 0;
      //rock1
      if (r3 == 0 && r4 == 0) {
        rock1.x = -50;
        rock1.y = r6;
        rock1.velocityX = movespeed;
        rock1.velocityY = 0;
      }
      if (r3 == 1 && r4 == 0) {
        rock1.x = r5;
        rock1.y = 450;
        rock1.velocityX = 0;
        rock1.velocityY = -movespeed;
      }
      if (r3 == 1 && r4 == 1) {
        rock1.x = 450;
        rock1.y = r6;
        rock1.velocityX = -movespeed;
        rock1.velocityY = 0;
      }
      if (r3 == 0 && r4 == 1) {
        rock1.x = r5;
        rock1.y = -50;
        rock1.velocityX = 0;
        rock1.velocityY = movespeed;
      }
      //rock2
      if (r7 == 0 && r8 == 0) {
        rock2.x = -50;
        rock2.y = r10;
        rock2.velocityX = movespeed;
        rock2.velocityY = 0;
      }
      if (r7 == 1 && r8 == 0) {
        rock2.x = r9;
        rock2.y = 450;
        rock2.velocityX = 0;
        rock2.velocityY = -movespeed;
      }
      if (r7 == 1 && r8 == 1) {
        rock2.x = 450;
        rock2.y = r10;
        rock2.velocityX = -movespeed;
        rock2.velocityY = 0;
      }
      if (r7 == 0 && r8 == 1) {
        rock2.x = r9;
        rock2.y = -50;
        rock2.velocityX = 0;
        rock2.velocityY = movespeed;
      }
    } else {
      count2 = count2 + 1;
    }
    //time counters
    if (count1 == 60) {
      time = time + 1;
      count1 = 0;
    } else {
      count1 = count1 + 1;
    }
    // PLAYER CONTROLS
    // change the y velocity when the user clicks "up"
    if (keyDown("up")) {
      player.velocityY = player.velocityY + -up;
    } else if (keyDown("down")) {
      player.velocityY = player.velocityY + up * 2;
    } else {
      player.velocityY = player.velocityY + up;
    }


    // decrease the x velocity when user clicks "left"
    if (keyDown("left")) {
      player.velocityX = player.velocityX - left;
      player.setAnimation("bird_left");
    } else if (player.velocityX < 0) {
      player.velocityX = player.velocityX + left / 4;
    }

    // increase the x velocity when the user clicks "right"
    if (keyDown("right")) {
      player.velocityX = player.velocityX + right;
      player.setAnimation("bird_right");
    } else if (player.velocityX > 0) {
      player.velocityX = player.velocityX - right / 4;
    }

    // SPRITE INTERACTIONS
    // reset the coin when the player touches it
    if (player.isTouching(coin)) {
      score = score + 1;
      coin.x = r1;
      coin.y = r2;
    }

    // make the obstacles push the player
    if (player.isTouching(rock1)) {
      rock1.displace(player);
    }
    if (player.isTouching(rock2)) {
      rock2.displace(player);
    }

    // DRAW SPRITES
    drawSprites();

    //time and score displayed
    textSize(12.5);
    fill("black");
    //score
    text("Score:", 15, 20);
    text(score, 55, 20);
    //high score
    text("High Score:", 15, 50);
    text(highScoreSave, 85, 50);
    //time
    text("Time:", 150, 20);
    text(time, 185, 20);
    //best time
    text("Best Time:", 150, 50);
    text(bestTime, 215, 50);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share some context besides "bestPoints" and a large amount of code, which does not run. Include what framework you are using, or edit the Stack Snippet I added to your question with enough HTML and other JavaScript so that others can reproduce what you are seeing. See [mre] for more.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is a divide by zero error in this line:

```
bestPoints = bestRunScore / bestRunTime
```

If `bestRunScore` or `bestRunTime` are zero, you will get the error.